# Binding objects to WinForms controls and access modifiers

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having some trouble understanding access modifiers; I want to know better when to use what level of access, especially for properties--just links to *good* tutorials on that subject could be its own question.

But more specifically, I don't understand why an object bound to a WinForm control has to be public. So I create my object:

```
public class Foos : List<Foo>
{
}

public class Foo
{
    private int bar;
    public int Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { bar = value; }
    }
}
```

then bind it to a `DataGridView`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Foos formFoos;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        formFoos = new Foos();
        AddFoo();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = formFoos;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generate some test values
    /// </summary>
    private void AddFoo()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.Bar = 5 * i;
            formFoos.Add(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine. But what if I don't want to expose `Foo.Bar` outside my assembly? If I make it `internal int Bar` I get an empty dataGridView1. If I make it `protected` I get a compiler error, because of course Form1 is not derived from Foo.

How does a control in a form in my program not match the definition of [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) though?

> Internal members are accessible only within files in the same
>   assembly.

General wisdom on how you make these declarations in a systematic way also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark the whole `Foo` class as `internal`.

This way, the entire `Foo` class and all it's members will be **invisible** outside the assembly.

`Form1.dataGridView1` needs `Foo.Bar` to be public, otherwise it won't be able to make use of it.

Now, because `Foo` is already marked `internal`, it can expose `Bar` as `public` with no risk of exposing it outside the assembly.

This should make both `Form1.dataGridView1` and you equally happy.

- Please note that by marking `Foo` as `internal`, `Foos` should also change from `public` to `internal` because `Foos` may not have a higher access level than the class it's derived from.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I guess I thought for some reason that a property could supersede a class access level.

Comment: It's confusing, I agree. Glad you got it sorted out.